# Android TextInputEditText settext missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: android

There is an error on :

> binding.textInputEditText.text

It shows

> Cannot access 'androidx.core.view.OnReceiveContentViewBehavior' which is a supertype of 'com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

but I can run the application

Comment: Please keep SO's Q&A format and don't put answer in the question post, neither add Solved in the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it has something to do with version conflict from dependencies. It is necessary to update some of the libraries associated with the given code (appcompat, material).

Comment: That's modular and a little bit complicated, I try to explain

Comment: Thank you, Solved this after updating androidx.appcompat:appcompat version

Comment: @HosseinKurd Happy to help!